# run jobs in Different Timezone in salesforce

Tags: apex

I have a Batch job which I want to run weekly for multiple timezones at 12 PM. Any suggestion on how I can achieve this.

Comment: How about adding the timezone logic in the code and executing the batch each hour?

Comment: You may be thinking about this in the wrong way. 12PM in multiple timezones is just multiple hours UTC/GMT. Depending on the timezones you need to support, just schedule the batch to run at key times (based on UTC) or try out Ysr Shk's idea.

Answer (score 1):

12PM in multiple time zones is just multiple hours UTC/GMT. Depending on the time zones you need to support, just schedule the batch to run at key times (based on UTC) or try out Ysr Shk's idea - particularly if you need this batch to run for more than 12 hours out of the day.

Example cron syntax if the user is in EST and wants to run a job at noon for every time zone across the United States: [`0 12,13,14,15,16,17 * * 1`](https://crontab.guru/#0_12,13,14,15,16,17_*_*_1).

To break this syntax down:

- `0` - at the beginning of the hour
- `12,13,14,15,16,22` - on the 12th hour (Noon), and the 13th (1 PM), 14th, 15th, 16th, and 17th (5 PM)

  - 12:00 EST => 12:00 Eastern Standard Time (EST UTC-5)
  - 13:00 EST => 12:00 Central Standard Time (CST UTC-6)
  - 14:00 EST => 12:00 Mountain Standard Time (MST UTC-7)
  - 15:00 EST => 12:00 Pacific Standard Time (PST UTC-8)
  - 16:00 EST => 12:00 Alaska Standard Time (AKST UTC-9)
  - 17:00 EST => 12:00 Hawaii Standard Time (HST UTC-10)
- `* * 1` - every Monday

I realize these hours line up one after the other, so you can also express this as `0 12-17 * * 1` but I included the comma syntax in case your time zones *do not* line up hour after hour.

Keep in mind the scheduler in Salesforce schedules the job based on the *scheduling user's time zone* so you can use a time zone converting tool to verify your scheduled times based on the user. You can also write unit tests and verify the schedule is accurate as well, see [Testing the Apex Scheduler.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm)